# Parse JSON for clean, pure text of the description in Google News feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, rss

I want to retrieve the pure text (without any HTML) of the `description` of stories found on Google News RSS feed that has been processed with Google AJAX API to convert RSS to JSON. **How would I parse the "JSON'd" feed to get clean `description`/`content` text as shown by the 2nd screenshot below?**

**Screenshots:**
raw rss: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQYmz.jpg
nice, clean description via Y! Pipes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGCSU.jpg

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/KuLQw/1/
**Can use $.text() on `description`/`content`, but how do I remove the extra related crap at the end?** (see comment on answer below)

```
$.getJSON('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=100&callback=?&q=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2F%3Foutput%3Drss', function(data){
    $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(i, item){
    // variables
    var title = item.title;
    var url = item.link;
    var pub_date = item.pubDate;
    var description = item.content;
    // rendering
    $('div.news').append('<div class="news-story"><p><a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a></p><div style="border: 1px solid red">'+$(item.content).text()+'</div></div>');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
var url='http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=2FV68p9G3BGVbc7IdLq02Q&_render=json&feedcount=10&feedurl=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2F%3Foutput%3Drss';

$.getJSON(url+'&_callback=?',function(x){

    $.each(x.value.items,function(k,v){
        $('#out').append('<div>'+v.title+'</div>');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h4H4p/

Comment: This works for the "title" only. I am looking for the clean, pure text of the "description".

Comment: Well...you can write description instead of title, but I think the problem is that the items array in your link is empty, so.. no posts, no description

Comment: what? I want the content of description in pure text without the tabular structure w/ images, related links, etc. My code above works: http://jsfiddle.net/KuLQw/

Comment: If you haven't already, install some json viewer in your browser to better understand the data structure. For example JSONViewer extension for Chrome renders this http://i44.tinypic.com/wl7zi1.jpg.

Comment: This is probably due to going over the request limits for that Yahoo! Pipe. It is not related to my direct question. You may use any other RSS to JSON converter (like Google AJAX API). I want to know how to sanitize "description" to only get text w/out the extra HTML crap.

Comment: @stewe awesome! I can't believe I overlooked $.text(). Now it need to be made pretty: add space between the source and beginning of description paragraph, trim it to remove the related crap at the end?

Comment: You could find the div with the class `lh` thats pretty much only the text itself. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6NMku/ .

Comment: switched my question to use the more reliable google ajax api to convert the rss to json. div.lh is not present when using $.text().

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not else than Javascript, so you access JSON data as you would access a simple Javascript object.
So your description is in `NAME_OF_YOUR_JSON_VAR.value.description`

Comment: I should've been more specific with my question. I am using jQuery $getJSON to retrieve the JSON'd feed (Google News RSS processed with Y! Pipes). I am having trouble getting the pure text of the "description" without tabular HTML structure.